ASP.Net Microsoft Web Report Viewer - Not Rendering Toolbar Buttons Correctly
I have the most basic of web pages setup with a Microsoft report viewer control dropped on it - when I run a simple report (local mode if that makes a difference) the buttons on the control toolbar don't line up. What can I do - is there some way of putting it in a DIV with some 'style' setting or anything.....it looks like garbage as it is (see pic).
I was previously using VS2013 and the 2012 report viewer control with no issues - I decided to put some effort in a revamp the whole project VS 2022 and release 150.1620.0 (the latest release) of the report viewer.
The aspx code for my page is:
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="ReportViewer2.aspx.vb" Inherits="_LBBCReports.ReportViewer2" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">body:nth-of-type(1) img[src*="Blank.gif"]{display:none;}</style> <!-- Bug Fix - Broken image fix in report viewer control -->
   
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewerControl" runat="server" Height="636px" ShowRefreshButton="False" Width="900px" BorderStyle="Solid"ShowBackButton="False"></rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

The image shows how it renders - look at the next/previous buttons....
If anybody has a fix for this please spoon feed it to me.....
ReportViewerImage
Tried stripping it down to bare basics on the page but that hasn't resolved it.
